# What is the name of this Swing component?

Tags: java, swing

I want to put one toolbar type component in which there will be one button which when pressed the toolbar should expand, size of the form increases and it contains some components like text area and label that user can see and once again when the button is pressed the toolbar is minimized and the size of the form decreases.

Can anybody tell me how to accomplish this?

e.g; like in windows 7 in my computer there is one toolbar called "Hard Disk Drives". When we press on it it shows all the drives and when we again press it it hides it.

Comment: please dont use uppercase titles...

Comment: "Home made" - there is no component in Swing that can do that. You could use a JButton when clicked, displays a JPopupMenu that would hold your extra controls, but you're going to have to make it yourself

Comment: search for java & ribbon or accordion

Comment: See also this duplicate question: [Explorer bar in java or any other component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895561/explorer-bar-in-java-or-any-other-component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) has a collapsible panel control that I think should do what you want.
Also take a look at [How to have Collapsable/Expandable JPanel in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177955/how-to-have-collapsable-expandable-jpanel-in-java-swing).

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

- You can add a [`JButon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) to a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html). In your button's `ActionListener`, open a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) containing your components. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513) illustrates some possibilities.
- For a more advanced view, consider `Outline`, illustrated [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

[image]